# Burn in protection for android wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watchface

Recently I started developing on android wear.
I read all about low ambient mode and burn in protection on the [design specs given by Google](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html).

For the low bit ambient mode we need to disable antialiasing and use no colors.

But do we need to take any action for the burn in protection? I know that it works by shifting the pixels by time so it protects the screen, but I am not sure, and it's not stated if that happens by the system or if we need to implement it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The watch will automatically move the image around - what you need to do is make sure the movement will be enough to prevent burn in. If you have, for example, a large hour hand, the burn in protection will kick in and move it a bit - but because of it's size, some of the pixels won't change (eg. from white to black), and therefore places burn in may be likely to occur.

Comment: There are also some specific suggestions at http://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html#SpecialScreens

Comment: Also, [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-providers/exposing-data-complications), "On screens susceptible to burn-in, solid blocks of color should be avoided in ambient mode. If your icons or images include solid blocks of color, you should also provide a burn-in safe version." For example, [ComplicationData.Builder has a setBurnInProtectionIcon method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/ComplicationData.Builder#setBurnInProtectionIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon))